# NSStatusBar menu bar icon NSMenu leaking CFData

Tags: objective-c, macos, memory-leaks, nsmenu

I have a weird data leak and hope someone can explain what is going wrong here. The minimal working example project is as follows:

1. Create a new Objective-C macOS project (Cocoa-App).
2. Delete everything except `Info.plist` and `main.m`
3. In `Info.plist` do:

   - Delete the entry `Main nib file base name`.
   - Change `Principal class` to "AppHook".
   - Add `LSUIElement` and set it to `YES`.

Next, change `main.m` to:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "AppHook.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    [[AppHook sharedApplication] run];
    return 0;
}
```

And add these two new files: `AppHook.h`

```
#import <Cocoa/Coco a.h>

@interface AppHook : NSApplication <NSApplicationDelegate, NSMenuDelegate>
@property (strong) NSStatusItem *barItem;
@end
```

and `AppHook.m`:

```
#import "AppHook.h"

@implementation AppHook
- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    self.delegate = self;
    return self;
}
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.barItem = [NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];
    self.barItem.highlightMode = YES;
    self.barItem.title = @"yep";
    self.barItem.menu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"M"];
    self.barItem.menu.delegate = self;
    self.barItem.menu.autoenablesItems = NO;
}
- (NSInteger)numberOfItemsInMenu:(NSMenu*)menu {
    return 1;
}
- (BOOL)menu:(NSMenu*)menu updateItem:(NSMenuItem*)item atIndex:(NSInteger)index shouldCancel:(BOOL)shouldCancel {
    item.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSDate date]];
    return YES;
}
@end
```

When running this application with Instruments and the Leaks template, I get following CFData leak:

```
0   Malloc      +1  1   00:03.319.300   AppKit  _DPSNextEvent
1   CFRetain    +1  2   00:03.319.303   AppKit  CopyCarbonUIElementAttributeValue
2   CFRelease   -1  1   00:03.319.310   AppKit  _DPSNextEvent
```

This happens every time the status menu is opened and closed. So hitting the menu icon repeatedly will create a bunch of leaks.

Nothing fancy here, just a subclass of `NSApplication` (I need to override `sendEvent(_:)`).

Comment: Is there an override of `sendEvent(_:)`? Or was that just by way of explaining why you're subclassing `NSApplication`? What are the backtraces of those three allocation events?

Comment: That was just to explain why I am subclassing it. The backtrace isn't helpful, pointing to `[NSApplication run]`. All other calls are system library e.g., `-[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:]`

Comment: I tried your code and I don't see any leaks (macOS 10.13.6).

Comment: Same OS version here. Very strange. I've deleted all caches and the DerivedData folder, restarted my mac and did everything else the same. Without modifications to the code the leaks disappeared. I will monitor that in the following days. I guess this leaking appears either after using the mac for a long time without reboot (uptime) or if xcode is open for a very long time (mine was running for a few weeks in the background)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ... after quite a long run it happend again.

### Short answer:

restart your Mac.

### Long answer:

As you can see my latest comment is nearly a month ago. Since then I restarted my mac twice and always checked Xcode Profiler before. For those two reboots the Profiler didn't show any leaks. I am not sure when the last reboot took place, roughly two weeks ago. Today I noticed that Profiler is showing the same leaks again.

What did **not** work:

- Cleaning the caches and DerivedData folder.
- Quit Xcode and restart it.
- Doing both and any other possible combination of these.

Seems to be a bug with macOS itself. I would create a bugreport but honestly, I wouldn't even know what to write. Reproducability is just by chance :-/
Also, it does not depend on a particular project. Used this sample project as reference and kept it without any changes in the last month.